# How to change dns information over a network

Tags: shell

I'm new to stackoverflow, so please bear with me. I'm also new to powershell, so I apologize in advance for that. However, we recently moved our servers, therefore we changed IP and DNS information. With that being said, I was given the task to change the DNS information on all of our clients' computers. Half were laptops, but the other half are desktops that are connected to our network. This was done, however, my boss gave me the wrong DNS information.. So, now I have to go back and do it over again.. And I really don't want to do it manually if I don't have to.. I was thinking that I could do the changes to the desktops with Powershell at the very least. Is there anybody that can help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. What I ended up doing was writing a bat file with netsh interface command prompt. Then I pushed it out to all of our stores.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I've done this in the past.  The problem you're going to have is narrowing down to the right adapter if you've got multiple that are IP enabled.  In my case, I knew that all the computers I was running this against had the same adapter service name.  If that's not your case, you may have to come up with a clever way to target the correct adapter.  Regardless, what you want to do CAN be done.

```
$AdapterServiceName = "myAdapterService"
$ComputerName = "."

$Adapter = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName|
where {$_.ServiceName -eq "$AdapterServiceName"}

$DNSArray = @()
$DNSServerPrimary = "192.168.1.100"
$DNSServerSecondary =  "192.168.1.101"

$DNSArray += $DNSServerPrimary
$DNSArray += $DNSServerSecondary   

$Adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(@($DNSArray))
```